# Multiple enums in datomic

Tags: enums, clojure, datomic

Is it possible to add multiple enums to an attribute in datomic ? Something like :

```
[{:artist/name "Leonard Cohen"
  :artist/countries  [:country/GR :country/CA] }
```

In this case  I get something like 
":db.error/not-an-attribute :country/GR is not an attribute"

However

```
[{:artist/name "Leonard Cohen"
  :artist/countries  :country/GR  }
```

would work

Comment: How is the schema definition for the `:artist/countries` attribute?

Comment: @GuillermoWinkler :

[{:db/ident :artist/countries
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [the James Bond example in the Tupelo-Datomic library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic#overview).  In short, when adding multiple `enum` attributes you need to wrap them in a set instead of a vector:

```
; Create some antagonists and load them into the db.  We can specify some of the
; attribute-value pairs at the time of creation, and add others later. Note that
; whenever we are adding multiple values for an attribute in a single step (e.g.
; :weapon/type), we must wrap all of the values in a set. Note that the set
; implies there can never be duplicate weapons for any one person.  As before,
; we immediately commit the new entities into the DB.
(td/transact *conn*
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "James Bond" :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/wit   } } )
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "M"          :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/guile } } )
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "Dr No"      :location "Caribbean"  :weapon/type    :weapon/gun                 } ))
```